# Implementing a Dispatch Table in Objective-C: how to declare an array of selectors

Tags: objective-c, dispatch, dispatch-table

I'm trying to implement a dispatch table, so that I can call a selector with the following example code:

```
NSInteger i = 2;
[myObject performSelector:selectors[i]];
```

I'm trying to store user preferences which affect which method of an API gets called. Right now, I use the string name of the selector and use NSSelectorFromString, but that's a bit messy. If I use a dispatch table, then I can store an enum instead.

How can I make an array of selectors, or a dispatch table in Objective-C?

**Edit:**

The compiler complains when I try to set an array of selectors as a property. `@property SEL[]` won't compile.

**Edit2:**

I'm using [my KosherCocoa API](https://github.com/mosheBerman/KosherCocoa/) library and I want to call a single method at once, based on a saved user setting. I'm saving to and reading from a Plist file.

Comment: Instead of doing that, perhaps the Strategy pattern would work better for you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `SEL` type to hold selectors. Simply:

```
SEL dispatchTable[3] = { @selector(doThis:), 
                         @selector(doThat:), 
                         @selector(doTheOther:) 
                       };
```

To your edit, use an `NSArray`/`NSDictionary`/etc of selectors as your property instead. You are not allowed to use C arrays as properties in Objective C; they are not one of the supported types (which are ObjC objects, CF types and basic C 'Plain Old Data' types.)

OK, on our comments below, you need to wrap the selector in an `NSValue` to allow you to use it in an objc container (because `SEL` is a C pointer type):

```
NSMutableArray * dispatchTable2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
SEL selIn = @selector(doThis:);

// Wrap the selector in an NSValue instance
[dispatchTable2 addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:selIn]];

// On extracting:
NSValue * valOut = [dispatchTable2 objectAtIndex:0];
SEL selOut = [[dispatchTable2 objectAtIndex:0] pointerValue];
[anObject performSelector:selOut];
```

So now your table is an objc container stored as a property or ivar, and you use `NSValue` to wrap `SEL` pointers with `valueWithPointer:` and get the `SEL` out with `pointerValue`.

Comment: Actually, there's a problem with using selectors in an array. Doesn't seem to work. I get an "Incompatible pointer" warning.

Comment: Can you post an example of the problem with some code? There's nothing wrong with declaring arrays of selectors.

Comment: Depends on scope, apparently. When I pasted your array into a method, it was fine, but if I put it into the implementation, outside of a method, it complains.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do this for a hundred pointers. That can get messy really fast, no?

Comment: A hundred selectors? What are you trying to build? Just in case it's not perfectly obvious you don't need to explicitly declare a hundred SEL variables; you can do the whole thing dynamically: [table addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(doThis:)]]; but ultimately if you have a hundred selectors, somewhere you're going to have to name them.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using NSInvocation instead of selectors. They are far more flexible, as you can send the same invocation to many objects and you can change its properties as you go.

Comment: More expensive than the other methods, sure. _Very_ expensive? How would you qualify that?

Comment: I would like to see some more info from @Moshe; the right solution depends on the problem.

Comment: OK, maybe for a hundred selectors it's not a very good idea to use NSInvocation.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using an array of `NSStrings`, then converting those to SELs at runtime, if that increases readability for you..

```
NSString *selectors[] = { ... } 

[myObject performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(selectors[i])];
```

To use this as a property, use

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSString **selectors;
```

Comment: just for the record, I tried using `@property(nonatomic, assign) NSString **selectors;` it gives error `pointer to non-const type NSString *with no explicit ownership`  while `@property(nonatomic, assign) void **selectors;` works